# Laravel validation didint working as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**UserController.php**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email'=>'required',
        'password'=>'required'
    ]);
    return "test";
}
```

**api.php**

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');
    Route::get('users', 'UserController@index');
 });
```

**Web.php.**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

if i pass email and password, it prints **test**. but when i miss either of parameter, it loads index.blade.php
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYBry.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Header` at `Postman` first.

```
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: can't see, permission issue

Answer (score 0):

Change the `login()` function like so

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return redirect(action('UserController@login')) // replace with your login route
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
           } 

            return "test";
        }
```

This might solve your problem.

Comment: It didnt solved. same as before. I dont know why this happens. Today i installed fresh laravel, passport and created authentication. nothing else

Comment: when i skip one parameter 404 not found error is displayed

Comment: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Answer (score 0):

You miss the conditions of validation fail.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return 'Success';
} else {
    return 'Error';
}
```

As per your current code, you are sending `return "test";` every time no matter with the validations

Comment: it returns success & failures.. but i think theres no need to check wheather validation fails or succeeds in new laravel version. it automatically return the validation error

Comment: @roopesh all it's depend on how you have coded for that, If you want direct redirect on the base of success and failed then It might be possible, for more info have a look: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators